# How to compare the performance of different indoor positioning system

Tags: indoor-positioning-system

I have integrated my app with 3 different indoor positioning libraries. Two of them are WiFi-based technology (infsoft and awiloc) and the third is a magnet field-based positioning (IndoorAtlas). Well, the results (accuracy, outliers, speed and position stability) are very different. This depends for a large scale on the calibration phase, which I performed for the three in same circumstances. What would be a fair test model in order to compare the performance of these libraries?

Answer (score 1):

There's been a bunch of scientific research that compares the accuracy of different navigation technologies in real-life situations. One that I found with a quick browsing was this: [https://ortus.rtu.lv/science/en/publications/12372/fulltext](https://ortus.rtu.lv/science/en/publications/12372/fulltext.).

To sum up:

1. Select a venue/venues
2. Walk a number of paths inside the building testing one technology
3. At selected locations, mark down on a floor plan your actual location and the location given by the technology. You can also write down the time taken for location fix.
4. Repeat the same with the other technologies
5. Measure the difference between actual locations and the locations given by the different technologies on the floor plan.

I would also repeat the same test in different types of venues to see if that affects the results.

Comment: Hi Annina, thank you. The accuracy of WiFi-based Positioning ist 5-10 Meter and the two positioning solutions I use delivere this. Accuracy is not the only aspect I want to test. It is interesting to know how would the system behave when the Smartphone is in a not calibrated place? What im looking for is a multi-aspect approach to test the different solutions according to accuracy, stability, speed and outliers.